# How do I get AppSettings as a constant value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appsettings

Take the code below

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="accesstoken:case1" value="00b8d5e4-a318-4f2d-bd5b-e7832861dbb6" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Controller.cs:

```
public JsonResult GetSomething(string token = "")
{
    switch (token)
    {
        case System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accesstoken:case1"]:
           ...
        case ...:
    }
}
```

So here I get an error for case1 saying a constant value is expected. And I had the impression that AppSettings was constant. But because it's being accessed in the way it is I suppose a constant is impossible.

But I really like switch/cases instead of having a bunch of if/elses, so is it possible to access AppSettings to get a constant value?

Comment: Constant inside a file doesn"t mean it is also a constant in the code. Constant in code always have a keyword `const`. It is not the same.

Comment: @CodeNotFound No, but there can be no argument if AppSettings in themselves are constants, so for versatility and clearity AppSettings should've been constants also in code. I cannot be the first person wanting to use AppSettings in switch/cases.

Comment: I understand your requirements, but I fear it can not be done. `const` must be baked into the code when it is compiled. Most you can aim for when reading from AppSettings at runtime is `readonly`, but `readonly` variables can also not be used as switch cases.

Comment: A `const`must be known at compile time. The values in`appsettings` are coming from an 'external' file so are not constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant inside a file doesn"t mean it is also a constant in the code. Constant in code always have a keyword `const`. It is not the same. Values configured inside the file settings can be modifiied during execution of your application. Constant fields can't be modified during execution.

A solution to achieve what you need to do without a bunch of `if-else` or `switch-case`  is at startup of you application to load a dictionary that will contain all key (e.g. starting with `accesstoken:*`)

```
public static Lazy<IDictionary<string, string>> AppSettingsAccessTokens = new Lazy<IDictionary<string, string>>(() =>
{
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Where(p => p.StartsWith("accesstoken:")).ToDictionary(p => p, p => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[p]);
});
```

And finally in your `GetSomething` method you do like:

```
public JsonResult GetSomething(string token = "")
{
    var accessTokenSettingKey = AppSettingsAccessTokens.Value.Values.FirstOrDefault(p => p == token)?.Key;

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Yes! But still with switch/cases - I swap them and use this for the switch and the keys as constant cases.